# Help to determine a basis for eigenspace

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Please find a basis for the eigenspace corresponding to eigenvalue=3 for the following matrix:
$$
\pmatrix{3&1&0\\0&3&1\\0&0&3}
$$
[3  1  0]
[0  3  1]
[0  0  3]

I have already calculated  [A-(lambda)I] and the result is the following augmented matrix:

```
 x1  x2  x3
[0   1    0    0]
[0   0    1    0]
[0   0    0    0]
```

From here I can see that:
* x1 is a free variable
* x2 y x3 are lead variables.

¿How is the basis determined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently $\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{pmatrix}\in\ker (A-3I)$ iff $x_2=x_3=0$. So the eigenspace is spanned by $\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: How do you get the "1" as the first element of the eigenvector?

Comment: It doesn't have to be a $1$ it could be any nonzero number. So in these cases it is customary to pick $1$

Comment: I want to make sure I understand. So if, for example, the [A - (lambda)I] matrix were: [0 0 1][0 0 0][0 0 0] then I would have x3 as a lead variable; and x1 and x2 free variables. From here I see that x3 = 0 and the basis would be [1  1  0]. x1 is always equal to x2. Am I correct?

Comment: x1 is not equal to x2, but x2 is equal to x3 in they are zero. In fact, you do not want to pick x1 = 0 Also, take a look at my little discussion with omnomnomnom regarding the use of "basis" here...

Answer (score 1):

So, you should be able to see that the solution to $(A - 3I)x = 0$ is given by
$$
x = \pmatrix{t\\0\\0} \quad t \in \Bbb R
$$
Since this solution space is, by definition, the eigenspace associated with $3$, the set $\{(1,0,0)^T\}$ forms a *basis* for this eigenspace.

Comment: Just a quick question: If I want to pick 3 independent eigenvectors, what would you suggest? After all, a basis could be formed?

Comment: @imranfat We can't pick $3$ independent eigenvectors in this case.  That is, this transformation is not *diagonalizable*.

Comment: Well I kind a thought so too, because the word "basis" is a little misleading here :)

Comment: @imranfat it's a basis for the eigenspace, but not for the entirety of $\Bbb R^3$.